# Error running firefox through java

Tags: java, shell, firefox, solaris

I have a java GUI whose button click event opens a particular jsp page present on a local tomcat server. In order to open that particular web page we use firefox and that also we didn't directly run firefox we execute a script in java which in turn execute firefox and loads the page. I know it seems quite weird but its not my design decision these are orders I need to follow. This Code is already written by someone else just got one problem with it on a particular server.

For Simplicity I have copied button click function code and made a new java program out of it as below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ProcessExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] envp = {"DISPLAY=:0.0"};
        Process p1 = null;
    try {
        p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/msatyam/test.sh", envp);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
    try {
        System.out.println(input.readLine());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProcessExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

The script that runs the firefox browser "test.sh" is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

firefox "localhost"
```

So, the above java code with the above shell script works fine for most of the systems, but
while testing the above code in one of our test server it fails and gives the following error on stdout:

*STDERR [ld.so.1: firefox-bin: fatal: libssl3.so: version 'NSS_3.12.6' not found 
(required by file /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so)

ld.so.1: firefox-bin: fatal: libssl3.so: open failed: No such file or directory

ld.so.1: firefox-bin: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so: symbol 
SSL_NumImplementedCiphers: referenced symbol not found Killed*

When we saw the above error, we thought there is some problem with firefox on this server, but we were wrong because when we ran the same script from the terminal it worked like a charm.

Test Server is running on Solaris 10.

And also I double checked for **libssl3.so** in this server which is present under directory:
**/usr/lib/firefox**

What could possibly be wrong as this shell script is working fine when run via terminal but doesn't work when run via above java code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you are removing all system environment variables before executing firefox, and replacing them all with the single variable `DISPLAY`.

You can run `env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 /home/msatyam/test.sh` to simulate what you're doing in Java from the command line.

If this reproduces the problem, you should instead get all the system's environment variable (using `System.getenv()`) and append `DISPLAY=:0.0` to that list, and then run your script.

Comment: but the same is working on a different server with same configuration. with only DISPLAY variable set. Still I will check as you suggested.Actually we can't access that test server very frequently so i would like to get each possible condition that can go wrong so that when I get access I can test each possible solution. Any more suggestion if found will be appreciated.